# How to apply style in an echo'ed <td>?

Tags: php, html, css

this is my PHP code:

```
$query="SELECT name, surname, address FROM employee";
$results = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
echo '<tr>';
foreach($row as $field) {
    echo '<td class="element">' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.element{
    color:red;  
}
```

But fields displayed in my HTML page aren't red. Why it doesn't work?

I already tried with

```
 echo "<td class='element'>" . htmlspecialchars($field) . "</td>";
```

and

```
 echo '<td class=\"element\">' . htmlspecialchars($field) . "</td>";
```

but with no success.

Comment: use your browser's dom inspector to see what rules ARE being applied. Maybe you've got a css syntax error somewhere earlier that's killing your `red` rule, or there's a `!important` override somewhere.

Comment: Get to know the tools of the trade: Chrome developer tools or Firebug for Firefox. Inspect the element and work from there. These tools will tell if the rule is applied and what other rules are applied

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to specify element in your css.

```
td.element{
    color:red;  
}
```

Also it's a good idea to give your  "tr" an ID
           "tr id="myTR"...

```
#myTR td.element{
    color:red;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

then try this.

```
echo '<td style="color:red">' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>';
```

even this 1 below shold work

```
echo '<td class="element">' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '</td>'; // for this just dont remove your css class
```

you just copy and paste to replace your code. and remove that class in css
 the issue of mysl_ does not affect that not to display, i am using latest php engine and they work fine, even though we need to change.